# Как определить название города

Tags: android, gps

Когда получаю координаты, вместо названия города показывается название района.

Используя `locationManager`, можно ли задать ему параметры (например, получить название города). Или все таки нужно будет реализовать другой метод, чтобы просто получить название города (конечно, такое не самый лучший вариант).

Comment: Мало подробностей в вопросе. Не все знают что за приложение вы делали и как у вас там что реализовано. Если вы используете станартный гугловый геокодер то там, вроде, есть в ответе вся доступная информация, включая страну.

Comment: Для получения такой информации, как страна, город, улица и прочее необходимо сделать HTTP geocoding request Yandex (бесплатный) https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/ или Google (платный). Geocoder, который встроен в SDK может порой вернуть null на некоторых устройствах (что очень плохо). По реализации у Вас опять два пути: HTTP запрос с распарсиванием JSON (что в принципе достаточно) или же использовать Retrofit (по красоте). Не забывайте также использовать асинхронный код, т.к. это запрос к сети и его нельзя осуществлять в основном потоке.

Comment: + Проверить на наличие связи с интернетом.

Comment: А вообще, `LocationManager` связан с провайдером, аля GPS, Network и т.д. А `LocationListener` относится к координатам. @ЮрийСПб правильно заметил, да и я хочу добавить то, что в вопросе вся информация, которая указана, никак вообще не относится к geocoder'у. Кроме вопроса собственно). P.S. Ни `LocationManager`,  ни `LocationListener` в этом не поможет.